# Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Q: Given $3^{x+y} = x^3 + 3y$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

I am convinced that, since it is not possible to algebraically solve for $y(x)$, one can't find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Am I correct?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a way to solve it and is called Implicit Differentiation. Very easy but non-intuitive and not algebraic in the sense you mean.Learn it will help lot.Hope I helped.

Comment: Write $y=y(x)$ (some function of $x$ that you are assuming is differentiable) and differentiate both functions (equal so their derivatives are equal)... just remember that the derivative of $y(x)$ --- the function you don't know --- well, all you can say is it is $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let$$f=3^{x+y}-x^{3}-3y=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} $$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-3^{x+y}ln3+3x^{2}}{3^{x+y}ln3-3}$$

I think so this might be enough! Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Just one thing I don't understand: why is it that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} $$?

Comment: this might help you : http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/PartialDerivatives.aspx  i had learnt it from my brother who is doing his 2nd yr engg.

Comment: This is the implicit function theorem?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal are you the same guy on brilliant?

Comment: Haha yes. :) :P :D

Answer (score 5):

Using the chain rule and implicit differentiation, we can write

\begin{equation*}
3^{x+y}\log(3)(\frac{d}{dx}(x+y))=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+3y)\\
\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(x)+\frac{d}{dx}(y)3^{x+y}\log(3)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+3y)\\
\Rightarrow 3^{x+y}\log(3)(1+y'(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+3y)\\
\Rightarrow 3^{x+y}\log(3)(1+y'(x))=3(\frac{d}{dx}(y))+3x^2\\
\Rightarrow 3^{x+y}\log(3)+3^{x+y}\log(3)y'(x)=3x^2+3y'(x).
\end{equation*}

Doing some manipulation and rearranging gives us

\begin{equation*}
y'(x)=\frac{3x^2-3^{x+y}\log(3)}{-3+3^{x+y}\log(3)}.
\end{equation*}